# Should I install baseboards before or after laminate flooring?

Tags: flooring, trim, laminate-floor

I am planning on having laminate flooring. The baseboards are not installed yet. Should I wait until the laminate is in first? Or should I do it before it is installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Baseboards should be installed after laminate.

Most (all?) Laminate is a floating flooring system which means it doesn't actually attach to the subfloor (friction holds it in place once all the pieces are set together.  As a result, it will expand/contract a bit with temperature/humidity changes in the house.  Because of this, you have to leave a small (quarter inch) gap around the outside edge.  The baseboards are then installed to cover the gap.

Also, laminate is very difficult to cut with a saw without at least minor chipping.  So unless you are going to buy a special cutter (looks like a large paper cutter), you are going to want to hide that cut edge.  Luckily, the way laminate is normally installed, the only cut edges are along the walls or transitions so they are covered.

Comment: I have used the "large paper cutter" type of laminate cutter, and while they are great for speed, ease of use and less saw dust, they do not produce perfect edges. Still recommended though.